# iteration through pages in html

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My purpose is to iterate through page, by click on every page and then take some information from it. I use selenium for Python.  My problem is that i cannot find any link/href where i should click the page in the HTML.

This is how is HTML looks like. I found list of pageNum, but when i click them, i get an error. When i looked more carefully into HTML, i found that i don't have and link there. So what i should do?

As you can see, below, i add some more HTML, "form method". I found it in the HTML too. Maybe it will help. As i compare the different href for pages, they consist of this module.

```
<a class="pageNum" rel="1" >1</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="2" >2</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="3" >3</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="4" >4</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="5" >5</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="6" >6</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="7" >7</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="8" >8</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="9" >9</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="10" >10</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="11" >11</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="12" >12</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="13" >13</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="14" >14</a>
<a class="pageNum" rel="15" >15</a>   


<form method="get" id="searchParams" action="https://www.ida.org.il/">
    <input type="hidden" name="pageType" value="19"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="langId" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="currPage" value="20"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="paramIds" value=",321,322,354,355,320"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="parameterSearch" value=""/>
</form>
```

here is the site: https://www.ida.org.il/?pageType=19&langId=1&paramIds=%2Con_321%2Con_322%2Con_354%2Con_355%2Con_320&scope=&parameterSearch=

Below you can see the columns i want to iterate.

Comment: Click the element you are clicking when doing it manually.

Comment: The element is "pageNum", but as you can see from the attached html, there are no href/link. Maybe there are Java Script function that create href when i click the "pageNum".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even without `href` attribute you can still click on the page number and be redirected. Use the `rel` attribute

```
page_number = 2
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[rel="' + page_number + '"]').click()
```

Comment: I have  a problem with page_number. It's a numeric and i should put there string. Python writes me an error.

Comment: @KDDExpert so just use string instead `page_number = '2'`